# Laravel Backpack List Not Displaying

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I can add data successfully, but while I am trying to load the list it does not show any data and showing an error message.

> Error loading page. Please refresh the page.

Also, I did not get any errors by inspecting the page. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by the "create data successfully"? Please provide more details and your current progress.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is most likely a misconfigured column.

I recommend you comment your `addColumn()` statements one by one, to see which one is the problem. Then take another look at how that  column is defined, using the docs.

Comment: thanks for the reply. As i did not use addColumn() method. I have 4 menus, all have the same problem. last week it worked fine. but I guess after updating composer the problem arises.

Comment: Ok. I recommend using ```addColumn``` instead of the ```setFromDb()``` - easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add data properly you either have a typo in your List function, or you have a different name for id in your table, that's what my problem was. To fix, add in your model :

protected $primaryKey = 'your_id';